# Python NumPy - how to limit array addition to max of dtype without conversion to larger dtype?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have 2 `uint8` arrays like this:

```
arr1 = np.array([50, 100, 150, 200, 250], dtype=np.uint8)
arr2 = np.array([50, 100, 150, 200, 250], dtype=np.uint8)
```

If I do array addition my intended result is:

```
[100 200 255 255 255]
```

i.e. when values get to the max value and then overflow, I'd like to keep the max value instead.  Simply doing addition does not work due to this overflow concern:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([50, 100, 150, 200, 250], dtype=np.uint8)
arr2 = np.array([50, 100, 150, 200, 250], dtype=np.uint8)

result = arr1 + arr2

print(result)
```

result (not as desired due to overflow for the last 3 numbers):

```
[100 200  44 144 244]
```

The easy around this is to convert to a larger datatype, so in this case `uint16`, then convert back like so:

```
arr1 = np.array([50, 100, 150, 200, 250], dtype=np.uint8)
arr2 = np.array([50, 100, 150, 200, 250], dtype=np.uint8)

arr1 = arr1.astype(np.uint16)
arr2 = arr2.astype(np.uint16)

result = np.where(arr1 + arr2 > 255, 255, arr1 + arr2).astype(np.uint8)
```

This gives the intended result:

```
[100 200 255 255 255]
```

But my question is, is there a more efficient way to do this that does not involve converting to the next larger dtype?

Comment: yes it looks like my questions is a duplicate, I'm not sure how I didn't find that when I searched